# KVM - failed to connect to the hypervisor error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm

I am trying to run kvm, but this error occurs:

```
$ virsh -c qemu:///system list
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
```

So I enter to:

```
cd /var/run/libvirt/
```

and changed privilages by:

```
sudo chmod -R +777 libvirt
```

Everything is working now, but I have concerns about security issues, as privileges for all users and groups is not the safest way to do it? What could you recommend instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add your user to the `kvm` and `libvirtd` groups:

```
sudo usermod -aG kvm $USER
sudo usermod -aG libvirt $USER
```

After these group changes you have to logout/login the terminal you are using to have the changes taken into account. The groups you belongs to, can be check with the `groups` command.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
sudo usermod -aG libvirt $USER
```

is the correct command

Answer (score 0):

Same error i was getting

[image]

Solution this helps:-

> #yum groupinstall "Virtualization Host"
>
> #yum install qemu-kvm libvirt libvirt-python libguestfs-tools virt-install
>
> #systemctl enable libvirtd.service

[image]

exit the use and re-login

Post above command executed, staring minkube i starting

[image]